# Query selector Class not working in Number Validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a Number validation in JavasCript.Works very well just in one input Number ,but I need some input's validation,I tried to do this with jquery selector class but it's only validating one of the them.How can I do this?

HTML:

```
<input id="dsa" type="number" class="css" min="0" max="10" />
<input id="dsa1" type="number" class="css" min="0" max="10" />
<input id="dsa2" type="number" class="css" min="0" max="10" />
```

JAVASCRIPT/Jquery

```
var input = document.querySelector('.css');
input.onkeyup = function testNums(evt) { 
var num = parseInt(evt.target.value, 10);

 if(typeof num === "number" && num < 11 && num > -1){
   evt.target.value = num
 }

 else{
  evt.target.value = ''
 }  


};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NL43y/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is your fiddle different than your code here?

Comment: sorry,I made a mistake.Check the new Fiddle.

Comment: And what is the jQuery code you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this: http://jsfiddle.net/Fa38e/

- jspref just for fun: http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id/72

Rest hope it fits your need `:)`

**code**

```
var input = $('.css');
input.keyup(function(evt) { 
     var num = parseInt(evt.target.value, 10);
    if(typeof num === "number" && num < 11 && num > -1){
        evt.target.value = num
    } else {
        evt.target.value = ''
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To select more than 1 element, use `querySelectorAll` - you'll then have to loop and bind each element, or use jQuery (as tagged)

```
$(".css").keyup(function(evt) {
    //code
});
```

Or looping (http://jsfiddle.net/NL43y/1/)

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll('.css');
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i].onkeyup = function testNums(evt) { 
        var num = parseInt(evt.target.value, 10);
        if(typeof num === "number" && num < 11 && num > -1){
            evt.target.value = num
        } else {
            evt.target.value = ''
        }  
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only calling it on one element `querySelector` only returns a single element, what you want is `querySelectorAll`. Heres an example without jQuery (http://jsfiddle.net/NL43y/2/)

```
var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.css'));

inputs.forEach(function (input) {
    input.onkeyup = function testNums(evt) { 
        var num = parseInt(evt.target.value, 10);
        if(typeof num === "number" && num < 11 && num > -1){
            evt.target.value = num;
        } else {
            evt.target.value = '';
        }  
    };
});
```

but if you used jQuery you could do this (http://jsfiddle.net/NL43y/3/)

```
$('.css').keyup(function(event) { 
    var num = parseInt(event.target.value, 10);

    if(typeof num === "number" && num < 11 && num > -1){
        event.target.value = num;
    } else {
        event.target.value = '';
    }
});
```